# Running Make. Is everything normal?

Tags: gcc, build, makefile

I'm trying to build gcc on a Synology DS209j. It is old and rather weak HW but I wonder whether everything is fine or not.

In the shell I have no output for the last 16 hours. The last output is:

```
build/genautomata ../.././gcc/config/rs6000/rs6000.md \
  insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
```

The top command reveals the process in state D and using on average 5% of the CPU. Is the build going on as expected or will it never finish? If it behaves as expected, why is the CPU utilization so low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what operating system you're using so it's hard to give suggestions.  First, of course, you can look at the contents of the `tmp-automata.c` file and see if it's being written to.  Also you can look at the timestamp of that file to see the last time it was updated.  If you're using Linux, you can run `strace -p <pid>` and see what system calls its making and try to get a feel for whether it's in an infinite loop or not.  Other variations of UNIX have similar commands.